# Ubuntu 18.04 No sound, laptop doesn't recognize speaker and says headphones are plugged in when they're not

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

The title, basically. A couple days ago, I also had the dummy output problem, but following directions on the internet I managed to solve it. However, a couple days later this series of problems started occuring. I've already tried to do a bunch of things in order to solve the problem, but none helped... I tried reinstalling pulseaudio and everything seems okay in alsamixer. My laptop doesn't even recognize the speakers, the only options for output are Headphones - Built-in Audio and HDMI/DisplayPort-Built-in Audio. I've also tried connecting my laptop to the TV and no sound there either. Any help?